# Django + South: Migrate from IntegerField to BigIntegerField, using Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south, biginteger

I'm working on a bugfix for a Django Model where we used an IntegerField and now we have numbers that are too big to fit in that field.  BigIntegerField looks like the obvious solution, but it's not working as expected.

I changed the field, ran manage.py schemamigration appname --auto, then applied the migration, but it's still returning DatabaseError: integer out of range.

I'm not database expert, but we suspect there might be a configuration problem with Postgres.  Does anyone have any experience with this sort of thing?

Right now I'm looking at having to make it a TextField, which will require me to do some annoying data move. Basically, I have to make a new secondary TextField, run schemamigration, write a script to move all the old integer values to the new TextField as strings, then remove the old IntegerField, schemamigration again to remove it from the DB. ugh.

Any suggestions on how to proceed are welcome.

Thanks